# I get Non-null field is not initialized by new on fields with @Inject

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, sonarqube, findbugs

I am working in an Eclipse RCP environment and I got a Service class which has some injected fields.

```
public class LContextService implements ILContextService {

     @Inject
     private IEclipseContext applicationContext;

     @Nullable
     private LContext activeContext;

     @PostConstruct
     public void postConstruct() {
         this.applicationContext.set(ILContextService.class, this);
     }

     @Override
     public LawsuitContext activateLContext(String context) {
         this.activeContext = this.someOtherHelperClass.setContext(context);
         return this.activeContext;
     }

....
```

}

Since this class will only be used by the dependency injection system I omit the default constructor and annotate the fields with @Inject to keep my code as slim as possible.
Package default is @NonNullByDefault.

Since the applicationContext is always available when initializing this class the default NonNull annotation is correct but the sonar error comes up anyways whenever I Inject such a field.

Can i get rid of these errors without completely deleting the rule?

P.S.: Just to be clear - I am implementing some different context, the activeContext field has nothing to do with the eclipse context or something like that.

Comment: I guess, it's not a FindBugs warning, but Eclipse one? If yes, please remove the `findbugs` tag.

Comment: No. The error comes from the sonar analyzing plugin stuff.
The error is also visible on the sonar page when I run the sonar-runner over my code.